# Parse json response using GSON in reterofit

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit

I have used the retrofit sdk for making api call. I have GSON sdk for parsing the response. I have some difficult to parse the json response. I have posted the json response below which is to be parsed.I need to get the address line arraylist.

I'm getting null data from the list.

```
{
    "QA": {
        "CreditsUsed": 1,
        "State": "Results"
    },
    "SearchResult": {
        "VerifyLevel": "Verified",
        "Address": {
            "AddressLine": [{
                "LineContent": "None",
                "Label": {},
                "Line": "2500Kearney St"
            }, {
                "LineContent": "None",
                "Label": {},
                "Line": {}
            }, {
                "LineContent": "None",
                "Label": {},
                "Line": {}
            }, {
                "Label": "City name",
                "Line": "Springfield"
            }, {
                "Label": "State code",
                "Line": "MO"
            }, {
                "Label": {},
                "Line": "65803-5048"
            }, {
                "Label": "Country",
                "Line": "UNITED STATES OF AMERICA"
            }],
            "DPVStatus": "DPVNotConfigured"
        },
        "VerificationFlags": {
            "StateProvinceChanged": true,
            "PostCodeCorrected": true
        }
    }
}
```

Model class

```
public class DineshValues {

    String Country;
    String Search;
    @SerializedName("LineContent")
    String LineContent;
    @SerializedName("Line")
    String Line;
    @SerializedName("AddressLine")
    List<AddressLine> data=new ArrayList();

    public List<AddressLine> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public String getLineContent() {
        return LineContent;
    }

    public void setLineContent(String lineContent) {
        LineContent = lineContent;
    }

    public String getLine() {
        return Line;
    }

    public void setLine(String line) {
        Line = line;
    }

    public void setData(List<AddressLine> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
    public String getCountry() {
        return Country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        Country = country;
    }

    public String getSearch() {
        return Search;
    }

    public void setSearch(String search) {
        Search = search;
    }
 }
```

AddressLine class file

```
public class AddressLine {

@SerializedName("LineContent")
@Expose
private String lineContent;
@SerializedName("Label")
@Expose
private String label;
@SerializedName("Line")
@Expose
private String line;

/**
* 
* @return
* The lineContent
*/
public String getLineContent() {
return lineContent;
}

/**
* 
* @param lineContent
* The LineContent
*/
public void setLineContent(String lineContent) {
this.lineContent = lineContent;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The label
*/
public String getLabel() {
return label;
}

/**
* 
* @param label
* The Label
*/
public void setLabel(String label) {
this.label = label;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The line
*/
public String getLine() {
return line;
}

/**
* 
* @param line
* The Line
*/
public void setLine(String line) {
this.line = line;
}
```

called like  this

```
RetrofitRest.getClient().getLogin("1111111" ,obj,new Callback<DineshValues >() {

  @Override
        public void success(DineshValues arg0, Response arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.e("size",arg0.getData+"");
        }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any exception? if yes then please edit question and add the complete logcat report. I guess when you are trying to print arg0.getData it is printing object address. Do one thing in the AddressLine  override toString method. Or go for arg0.getData.get(0).getLineContent()

Comment: 09-09 05:54:53.515: E/AndroidRuntime(1411): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0  Im getting the error while im using  arg0.getData.get(0).getLineContent().

Comment: i think i have done some wrong over creating pojo class for the given response ...can u check my pojo class ?

Comment: Please [edit] the question with the exception message

Comment: Each Label and Line attribute are not strings, they are objects, as noted by `{}`. Are you sure your Java classes are correct?

Comment: yes...i think gson parsing not working properly

Answer (score 0):

I have rectified the json it has extra "," as shown below.

```
"StateTransition":"SearchResults",
```

Upon parsing rectified json in http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/ . I noticed that In your jsonObject you have further 2 jsonObject with keys "CAB" and "Result". In your second jsonObject you have another jsonObject with key "Address" within which you have "AddressLine" array.

**SO Please rectify the complete pojo DineshValues.** 
If you need any further help then let me know I will add complete POJO

**UPDATE**

**Solution 1 -** 
 As mentioned in comment that you used jsonschema2pojo to generate pojo, you can keep those classes which might simply the code and use the following line to extract address

```
List<AddressLine> addressLine = arg0.getResult().getAddress().getAddressLine()
```

Now iterate addressLine and extract the data you need.

> Note - 1)Make sure arg0 is of type class for root JsonObject.
>   
> 2)Another point is as mention by cricket_007 - Each Label and Line
>   attribute are not strings, they are objects, as noted by {}.

**Solution 2 -** 
 You can only keep the AddressLine class from the generated class file in your project and use the following lines to extract address.

```
RetrofitRest.getClient().getLogin("1111111" ,obj,new Callback<DineshValues >() {

  @Override
        public void success(String arg0, Response arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            JsonObject rootJsonObject = new JsonObject(arg0);
            JsonObject searchResultJsonObject = rootJsonObject.getJsonObject("SearchResult");
            JsonObject addressJsonObject = searchResultJsonObject.getJsonObject("Address")

            Type listType = new TypeToken<List<AddressLine>>(){}.getType();
            List<AddressLine> addressLineList = gson.fromJson(addressJsonObject, listType);
            //Now iterate the addressLineList to get the address
             Log.e("size",addressLineList.getSize+"");

        }
}
```

Comment: @cricket_007 Totally agree with you. Initially I was thinking to add it as comment. So I had used tag. Thank you for editing it.

Comment: i have given the complete response... i have to get  (AddressLine) array list..how can i get this...provide the steps to acheive it

Comment: give the pojo class for the given response.. i have use (http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) for generating pojo..but i generated lot of classes.but i need address values only

Comment: @DineshkumarArunachalam Please check updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below POJO,

**Address**

```
public class Address {

    @SerializedName("AddressLine")
    private List<AddressLine> addressLine = new ArrayList<AddressLine>();
    @SerializedName("DPVStatus")
    private String dPVStatus;

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The addressLine
     */
    public List<AddressLine> getAddressLine() {
        return addressLine;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param addressLine
     *     The AddressLine
     */
    public void setAddressLine(List<AddressLine> addressLine) {
        this.addressLine = addressLine;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The dPVStatus
     */
    public String getDPVStatus() {
        return dPVStatus;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param dPVStatus
     *     The DPVStatus
     */
    public void setDPVStatus(String dPVStatus) {
        this.dPVStatus = dPVStatus;
    }

}
```

**AddressLine**

```
public class AddressLine {

    @SerializedName("LineContent")
    private String lineContent;
    @SerializedName("Label")
    private String label;
    @SerializedName("Line")
    private String line;

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The lineContent
     */
    public String getLineContent() {
        return lineContent;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param lineContent
     *     The LineContent
     */
    public void setLineContent(String lineContent) {
        this.lineContent = lineContent;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The label
     */  
    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param label
     *     The Label
     */
    public void setLabel(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The line
     */
    public String getLine() {
        return line;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param line
     *     The Line
     */
    public void setLine(String line) {
        this.line = line;
    }

}
```

**Data**

```
public class Data {

    @SerializedName("QA")
    private QA qA;
    @SerializedName("SearchResult")
    private SearchResult searchResult;

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The qA
     */  
    public QA getQA() {
        return qA;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param qA
     *     The QA
     */   
    public void setQA(QA qA) {
        this.qA = qA;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The searchResult
     */   
    public SearchResult getSearchResult() {
        return searchResult;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param searchResult
     *     The SearchResult
     */   
    public void setSearchResult(SearchResult searchResult) {
        this.searchResult = searchResult;
    }

}
```

**QA**

```
public class QA {

    @SerializedName("CreditsUsed")
    private Long creditsUsed;
    @SerializedName("State")
    private String state;

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The creditsUsed
     */
    public Long getCreditsUsed() {
        return creditsUsed;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param creditsUsed
     *     The CreditsUsed
     */   
    public void setCreditsUsed(Long creditsUsed) {
        this.creditsUsed = creditsUsed;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The state
     */   
    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param state
     *     The State
     */   
    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

}
```

**SearchResult**

```
public class SearchResult {

    @SerializedName("VerifyLevel")
    private String verifyLevel;
    @SerializedName("Address")
    private Address address;
    @SerializedName("VerificationFlags")
    private VerificationFlags verificationFlags;

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The verifyLevel
     */   
    public String getVerifyLevel() {
        return verifyLevel;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param verifyLevel
     *     The VerifyLevel
     */   
    public void setVerifyLevel(String verifyLevel) {
        this.verifyLevel = verifyLevel;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The address
     */   
    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param address
     *     The Address
     */
    public void setAddress(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The verificationFlags
     */   
    public VerificationFlags getVerificationFlags() {
        return verificationFlags;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param verificationFlags
     *     The VerificationFlags
     */  
    public void setVerificationFlags(VerificationFlags verificationFlags) {
        this.verificationFlags = verificationFlags;
    }

}
```

**VerificationFlags**

```
public class VerificationFlags {

    @SerializedName("StateProvinceChanged")
    private Boolean stateProvinceChanged;
    @SerializedName("PostCodeCorrected")
    private Boolean postCodeCorrected;

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The stateProvinceChanged
     */   
    public Boolean getStateProvinceChanged() {
        return stateProvinceChanged;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param stateProvinceChanged
     *     The StateProvinceChanged
     */   
    public void setStateProvinceChanged(Boolean stateProvinceChanged) {
        this.stateProvinceChanged = stateProvinceChanged;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The postCodeCorrected
     */   
    public Boolean getPostCodeCorrected() {
        return postCodeCorrected;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param postCodeCorrected
     *     The PostCodeCorrected
     */  
    public void setPostCodeCorrected(Boolean postCodeCorrected) {
        this.postCodeCorrected = postCodeCorrected;
    }

}
```

**Retrofit Call**

```
RetrofitRest.getClient().getLogin("your text", obj, new Callback<Data>() {
            @Override
            public void success(Data data, Response response) {
                SearchResult searchResult = data.getSearchResult();
                if (searchResult != null) {
                    Address address = searchResult.getAddress();
                    if (address != null && address.getAddressLine() != null) {
                        for (AddressLine addressLine : address.getAddressLine()) {
                            Log.d("TAG", "addressLine" + addressLine);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: i try all those things..but still i get null on Data object...    public void success(Data data, Response response) {

Comment: String Country;
 String Search;

  public String getCountry() {
  return Country;
 }

 public void setCountry(String country) {
  Country = country;
 }

 public String getSearch() {
  return Search;
 }

 public void setSearch(String search) {
  Search = search;
 }  Data obj=new Data();
  obj.setCountry("NewJersey");
  obj.setSearch("@2500 East Kearney Street,@,@,@Springfield,@MO,@65803");

Comment: i add these lines in Data class for passing post parameters to reterofit

Comment: Have you tested the API request/response using any rest client plugins(postman,Restclient,...etc) ?. Please make sure you have got the correct JSON response